# Change div's "perceived window width"

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe, material-ui, jss

I want to make the content of a div respond to its size, much like if
it was an iframe, but I can't use one.
My intent is to make the content adapt as if it was in a real smaller
screen so the user can preview the div content on mobile devices.
The iframe works, but it breaks react's diff algorithm, so I can't change the frame contents using the parent props anymore.

So, I want to be able to resize a div which will make it's contents responde
to it's media queries like if they are on a smaller window.

```
const Index = ({format}) => {
  const classes = useStyles ({format})
  // if I use iframe instead of div, the breakpoints works,
  // but it breaks a lot of app logic
  return <div className={classes.root}>
    <ChildrenToPerceiveBreakpoint/>
  </div>
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: props => ({
    overflow: props?.format ? 'auto' : 'visible',
    maxWidth: props?.format === 'mobile'
      ? 'min(414px, 100%)'
      : props?.format === 'tablet'
      ? 'min(768px, 100%)'
      : '100%',
    maxHeight: props?.format === 'mobile'
      ? 'min(736px, 100%)'
      : props?.format === 'tablet'
      ? 'min(1024px, 100%)'
      : '100%',
    margin: '0% auto',
    marginTop: props?.format === 'mobile'
    && theme.breakpoints.down('md')
      ? '5%'
      : '0%',
  }),
}))
```

I'm using material-ui and jss for the styling.

Thx!

Comment: Can you give your html and css code?

Comment: You need CSS transform scale (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

Comment: Actually, I want to fake a viewport so the inner elements will trigger the associated css media-queries. Scaling will just stretch or deform them. I want to implement something similar to storybook-viewport.